# I can't able to install gunicorn whitenoise in heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my `python-django website on heroku` .I used the command

```
(firstproject) $ pip install dj-database-url gunicorn whitenoise
```

I got an error like this

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): dj-database-url in /home/aparna/firstproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gunicorn in /home/aparna/firstproject/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking whitenose
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement whitenose
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for whitenose
Storing debug log for failure in /home/aparna/.pip/pip.log
```

How can I solve this error to deploy my website on heroku?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying that you typed `whitenose` rather than `whitenoise`.